# WaitForSingleObject on signalled thread gives WAIT_FAILED, why?

Tags: multithreading, mfc, thread-safety, wait

I have a Multithreaded code with a reset thread defined as:

```
bool CTestShellDlg::ResetThreads()
{
//if Main worker thread already finished, Just Reset
    if (CheckMainThreadFinished())
    {
        //reset
    }
    else 
        if(KillThreads())  //Go ahead and reset if killing is finished.
        {
            //reset
        }
    else
        return false; //killing already in progress. gotta wait!
}
```

And KillThreads() is defined as:

```
bool CTestShellDlg::KillThreads()
{
//if killing not already in progress
if (!CheckKillEvent())
{

    //Signall the killing event
    SetEvent(h_KillEvent);

    if (WaitMainThreadFinished())
    {
        //call some deletes
        //Reset the kill event back to non-signalled to indicate it's no longer in progress
        ResetEvent(h_KillEvent);
        return true; //Killing successful
    }
    else IERROR
}
else
    return false; //Killing already in progress
```

}

With

```
bool WaitMainThreadFinished(){WaitForSingleObject(m_hDoIt_Thread, INFINITE);...}
bool CheckMainThreadFinished(){WaitForSingleObject(m_hDoIt_Thread, 0);...}
```

Now, I can Call KillThreads() fine. During this process, I WaitForSingleObject(m_hDoIt_Thread, INFINITE) so I know by the end of it, it's definitely signaled. Now if I try to call ResetThreads(), my WaitForSingleObject(m_hDoIt_Thread, 0) in CheckMainThreadFinished() gives me WAIT_FAILED whereas in my understanding it should be WAIT_OBJECT_0. What could possibly cause that?
What is interesting. Is that if I make two consecutive ResetThreads() calls, I don't get the said return value from CheckMainThreadFinished().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! 
Used GetLastError() and it turned out the handle for

```
WaitForSingleObject(m_hDoIt_Thread, 0);
```

was invalid. The reason for that is By default an MFC thread frees its thread handle and deletes the thread object when it exits. That leaves you with an invalid thread pointer and handle, so this way of checking if the main handle is working will not work and an alternative should be used.

Comment: Just FYI: you can set [mb_AutoDelete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4bbe9bte%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to FALSE

Comment: Interesting thing you mentioned! I had in fact set  mb_AutoDelete=False to keep the pointers and handles. How do I delete a thread that is actaully finished? TerminateThread?

Comment: Do not use TerminateThread. It is not recommended to be used. Read MSDN about it. The m_bAutoDelete applies only to the CWinThread object. If you have created the thread with m_bAutoDelete = FALSE you need to store the pointer of the CWinThread object and delete it after the thread is finished

Comment: To clarify, the "child" worker threads  m_bAutoDelete=false, whereas the "parent" worker thread which called these threads had it as default, which is why my CheckMainThreadFinished() was failing. So yes I do have the pointers to these threads. But how do I delete the actual threads, as opposed to the pointers pointing to them?

Comment: So the only point of m_bAutoDelete is to keep the pointer and handles alive? So all the variables defined in the "finished" thread gets deleted at the point that it finishes?